# Delete branch with cyrillic title

Tags: git, bitbucket

I am trying do delete branch with cyrillic title in Bitbucked. When I select from Actions>Delete I get this message **"Page not found. We couldn't find the page you requested."** When I try to delete it from cmd with

`git push origin --delete <my_cyrillic_titled_branch>`

I get this error:

`error: unable to delete '<my_cyrillic_titled_branch>': remote ref does not exist
error: failed to push some refs to '<repo_url>'`

UPDATE:
I use Centos 7 and git version 1.8.3.1

How should I delete it ?

Comment: Try git push origin :refs/heads/cyrillic_branch_name

Comment: No, it does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> from cmd

Do you work in Windows' command line? That's the problem, I guess; try [Git Bash](https://git-for-windows.github.io/#bash), because Git and Bitbucket both work with cyrillic without any problems:

```
user@nohostname:~/development/bitbucket.org/storage> git --version                                                                                                               
git version 2.7.4                                                                                                                                                                               

user@nohostname:~/development/bitbucket.org/storage> git checkout -b ветка
Switched to a new branch 'ветка'

user@nohostname:~/development/bitbucket.org/storage> git push -u origin ветка
Password for 'https://*********@bitbucket.org': 
Total 0 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: 
remote: Create pull request for ветка:
remote:   https://bitbucket.org/*********/storage/pull-requests/new?source=%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0&t=1
remote: 
To https://*********@bitbucket.org/*********/storage.git
 * [new branch]      ветка -> ветка                                                                        
Branch ветка set up to track remote branch ветка from origin.
```

[image]

```
user@nohostname:~/development/bitbucket.org/storage> git push -u origin :ветка
Password for 'https://*********@bitbucket.org':                                                                                                                                            
To https://*********@bitbucket.org/*********/storage.git                                                                                                                              
 - [deleted]         ветка
```

[image]

Comment: @Ivan try putting branch's name into quotes. Smth like this `git push origin :"ветка"`.

Comment: It worked. The problem was that I have "–" in the name but I was trying to delete it with "-". Thank you for helping me :)